# How to use bazel to build tensorflow as external dependencies to support gpu inference?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I want to use tensorflow's c++ api to inference in my project, when I build it for cpu, it's ok. But when I build it for support gpu (bazel build --config=cuda ...), it has some error.

My WORKSPACE:

```
http_archive(
  name = "org_tensorflow",
  strip_prefix = "tensorflow-1.15.0",
  sha256 = "a5d49c00a175a61da7431a9b289747d62339be9cf37600330ad63b611f7f5dc9",
  urls = ["https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/archive/v1.15.0.tar.gz"]
)

load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace.bzl", "tf_workspace")
tf_workspace(tf_repo_name = "org_tensorflow")

# Uncomment the following two lines has the same error.
# load("@org_tensorflow//third_party/gpus:cuda_configure.bzl", "cuda_configure")
# cuda_configure(name="local_config_cuda")
```

My .bazelrc:

```
...
# config for using cuda
build:cuda --define=using_cuda=true --define=using_cuda_nvcc=true
build:cuda --action_env TF_NEED_CUDA=1
build:cuda --crosstool_top=@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain
...
```

My BUILD:

```
cc_library(
    name = "tf_utils",
    srcs = ["tf_utils.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["tf_utils.h"],
    deps = ["@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/cc/saved_model:loader"
            "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:tensorflow"]
)
cc_binarary(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["test.cpp"],
    deps = ["tf_utils"]
)
```

When I run `bazel build --config=cuda //:test`

The error message is：

```sh
ERROR: external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:405:1: C++ compilation of rule '@com_google_protobuf//:protoc' failed (Exit 1) crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -MD -MF bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/_objs/protoc/main.d ... (remaining 46 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:413: "execvp(external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc, 0x6dfe10)": No such file or directory
Target //:test failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

The error message shows no such file or directory, but it does exist.

```sh
# ls -la external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 9129 Dec  1 14:14 external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc*
```

The tensorflow version is 1.15, bazel version is 3.1.0.

Does anyone know how to configure bazel correctly so that tensorflow can support gpu as an external dependency? Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If so, tell me how

Comment: Did you tried instructions mentioned in the [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source). Thanks!